# $n$-dimensional limits of integration after change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

What is a general procedure for finding limits of integration after a change of variables in multiple dimensions? There are many examples of doing this in 2d (and maybe some in 3d) but they all seem to rely on being able to inspect the volumes geometrically, which is hard enough in 3d and seems impossible in general $n$-d space.

Let's assume that we have a linear transformation from one set of coordinates $\mathbf{x}$ to another $\mathbf{y}$ given by some matrix $\mathbf{A}$,ie

$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{Ax}
$$

and that we are given explicit limits of integration of an $n$-d cuboid in $\mathbf{x}$ coordinates. This cuboid has $2^n$ vertices, which gives $2^n$ equations that map these vertices from the old coordinates to the new ones. However, we only need $2n$ limits of integration, not $2^n$. How do we resolve this?

Also, can it happen that explicit limits in this one set of coordinates becomes instead a function of other variables in the other coordinates? What is a procedure for finding these functions under such transformations where we can't "draw" the regions and inspect them?

**Add 1**

Is the procedure to have two sets of equations with one where we fix all values of $\mathbf{x}$ to their upper limit and solve for $\mathbf{y}$ and the other set with all values fixed to the lower limits of $\mathbf{x}$?

So, if the limits of integration in $\mathbf{x}$ are given by $\mathbf{x_L}$ and $\mathbf{x_U}$, then

$$
\mathbf{x_L} \le \mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{x_U} \\
\mathbf{Ax_L} \le \mathbf{Ax} \le \mathbf{Ax_U} \\
\mathbf{Ax_L} \le \mathbf{y} \le \mathbf{Ax_U} \\
$$

where the inequalities are to be understood element-wise. Is this correct?... When I think of, for example, a cube in 3d with edges along positive semi-axis and vertices defined with $0$s and $a$s, ie $[0,0,0]$, $[a,0,0]$, $[0,a,0]$, etc, and with the change of coordinates given by a rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ around one of the axis by, say, $45°$ then the above approach would give explicit values for the limits of integration in the transformed coordinates, but shouldn't these limits be now functions of other variables since the edges of the cube are not aligned with two of them?

If we think of the volume of a cube as an integral of a function $f(x_1, x_2) = a$ over $0 \le x_1 \le a$ and $0 \le x_2 \le a$ and if we rotate to new coordinates by $45°$, for which the rotation matrix is given by

$$
\mathbf{R} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$

then the above method would give

$$
\mathbf{x_L} \le \mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{x_U} \\
\mathbf{0} \le \mathbf{x} \le a\mathbf{1} \\
\mathbf{R0} \le \mathbf{Rx} \le a\mathbf{R1} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\le 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\le a\sqrt{2} 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
$$
which doesn't really make sense, so I guess that's not the way to go about it.

**Add 2**

If instead of applying the transformation to the vectors as described in "Add 1" above, I substitute for $x$s in terms of $y$s, I get

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\le 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\le  
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
a \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 - y_2 \\
y_1 + y_2\\
\end{bmatrix} 
\le  
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
a \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
-y_1 \\
-y_1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\le 
\begin{bmatrix}
-y_2 \\
y_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\le  \sqrt{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
a \\
\end{bmatrix}
-
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
- \sqrt{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
a \\
\end{bmatrix}
\le
\begin{bmatrix}
y_2 \\
-y_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\le
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which can be also written as

$$
y_1 - a\sqrt{2} \le  y_2 \le y_1 \\
-y_1 \le y_2 \le a\sqrt{2} - y_1
$$

and for both of these to be satisfied simultaneously we need to have

$$
\max\{-y_1, y_1 - a\sqrt{2}\} \le y_2 \le \min\{y_1, a\sqrt{2} - y_1\}
$$

and this now seems to have the correct dependence of $y_2$ range on $y_1$, but it doesn't give any explicit limits for $y_1$, so doesn't seem to offer a complete solution either.

It is also not quite clear how to generalize this to higher dimensions since this approach gives limits only for one variable in terms of the others, but we need limits for all of them and if we are to repeat this procedure for other variables then we would just end up with a situation where the limits for each variable are in terms of all other variables.

Comment: Well, think about how you resolve it in $\mathbb R^3$. There you also have $2^3 = 8$ vertices, but only $6$ limits.

Comment: Also, take a look how [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) works in higher-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @red_trumpet Thank you for your comments. I have tried to apply substitution of variables to find the limits (see "Add 2" section of my post), but I am not able to get the results even in 2 dimensions, let alone 3. Would you be able to provide some further guidance?  Many thanks